# Check if rows of matrix are all the same

Tags: r, equals

```
m1 = matrix(c(2,1,4,3,5,6),ncol=3)
m2 = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,6,5),ncol=3)
m1==m2
```

I need to show that `m1=m2` because their rows are the same. Any way to do it?

Comment: I think you need `all.equal( m1[do.call(order, as.data.frame(m1)),], m2)`

Comment: this is a simplified case where there are only 2 columns. If there are more, I can't order the columns based on the first one. Is it still valid?

Comment: It is still valid.  Do you expect a single TRUE/FALSE or each row TRUE/FALSE.  In that case `rowSums(m1[do.call(order, as.data.frame(m1)),] == m2) == ncol(m2)
[1] TRUE TRUE`

Comment: Thank you, great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a single TRUE/FALSE as output, use either `all.equal` or `identical` after `order`ing the row of one of the dataset (or both - if both are not ordered. In this example, 'm2' is already ordered)

```
all.equal( m1[do.call(order, as.data.frame(m1)),], m2)
```

If it should return TRUE/FALSE for each row, create a condition with `rowSums`

```
rowSums(m1[do.call(order, as.data.frame(m1)),] == m2) == ncol(m2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setdiff()` to make it, where you treat rows as sets and calculate their difference, i.e.,

```
length(setdiff(data.frame(t(m1)),data.frame(t(m2))))==0
```

such that

```
> length(setdiff(data.frame(t(m1)),data.frame(t(m2))))==0
[1] TRUE
```